Why does yarn prisma studio error with 'error in Prisma Client request'?
I have nextJS app and I am using Prisma and psql which I really like. When I started the project, Prisma studio worked like a charm, now when I try to run the studio I get an error which I don't know how to address.
Message: Error in Prisma Client request: Invalid `f=e.match(mgt)?.[1]??"",g=e.match(hgt)?.[1]??null,v=e.match(ggt)?.[1]??null,{getPrismaClient:E,PrismaClientKnownRequestError:x,PrismaClientRustPanicError:S,PrismaClientInitializationError:C,PrismaClientValidationError:A}=require(`${c.prismaClient}/runtime/${u}`),O=e,I=(0,Rk.createHash)("sha256").update()` invocation in .../node_modules/prisma/build/index.js:1825:10334 any ideas?
Tried deleting node modules, rebuilding the app. Tried changing schema.prisma an generating to no avail.
What is even more weird, I can actually get the data from DB and writing to DB works, so I am perplexed.

npx prisma db push Fix it mor me or you can check your connection string

You can try the npx prisma generate command to regenerate the Prisma Client. This can sometimes resolve issues caused by changes in the schema or environment.

I have tried that and I get the same result.
